# Why does this imply a congruence does not exist?

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Consider

$$kx \equiv a \bmod M$$

Where $x,a,M$ are known, solving for $k$. Let $g = \gcd(M,x)$. Why is it the case that if $g$ does not divide $a$, there is no solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the solution exists, the congruence can be rewritten as $kx-a=Mj$ for some integer $j$. This implies $kx-Mj=a$. The left side is divisible by $g$. So for the equality to hold right side must also be divisible by $g$.

Comment: Wow, how do you even see something like this? That's amazing. I've been staring at this with no progress for hours. Did you just put both arguments of the gcd on one side of the congruence and go from there? Or is this a well known fact?

Comment: @WillStein to deal with divisibility issues usually putting things on one side can be helpful.

Comment: @WillStein It might help if you gave us some insight into what kind of things you tried during those hours of staring, suggest some more general problem-solving strategies you might have tried :).

Comment: @ErickWong All the wrong things apparently. I was trying to do things like $gi = M$ and $gj = x$ and then manipulate that, but it wasn't getting me anywhere because I couldn't find a way to relate it to $a$ properly.

Comment: @WillStein Ah, well here are some general thoughts for what it's worth.  You need to prove "if $g \nmid a$ then there is no solution".  A premise such as $g\nmid a$ is not very definite so it is often not practical to work with.  This gives a clue that you might want to start from the contrapositive: "if there is a solution then $g \mid a$".  Once you assume a solution, you have that $kx \equiv a \mod M$.  At this point you can easily combine it with $gi=M$ and $gj=x$ to get $gkj \equiv a \mod gj$...From there you'd be pretty close to showing that $a$ is divisible by $g$, no?